# Show that $x \equiv 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $x \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$ then $x \equiv 0 \pmod{ab}$?

Use of CRT, but that doesnt seem to work here?

Comment: What about $x=b=20$, $a=10$

Comment: It works, $x \equiv 0$,but how to prove it?

Comment: It doesn't work, read @wet's counterexample again. Or consider that *if* it worked it would imply that if $x$ is a multiple of $a$ then $x$ must be a multiple of $a^2$, which is obviously false. You are missing an assumption.

Comment: @dxiv The given statement is true only if (a, b) = 1? Should I put this as an answer?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I can't guess what's missing. The conclusion holds if $(a,b)=1$, but it also holds if you replace $\pmod{ab}$ with $\pmod{\text{lcm}(a,b)}$ for example.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes, make an answer

Comment: Note that this statement holds if $(a,b)$ are prime numbers...(prime factors of $x$)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x\equiv0\bmod a$ and $x\equiv0\bmod b$ can be written more concisely as $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$. Given these two conditions, only 
$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mid x$ is always true; $ab\mid x$ is true if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

For example, if $a=6$, $b=15$ ($\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=30$) and $x=120$, $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ are true, but $ab\mid x$ is not true; only $30\mid x$ is true.