# $a|x$ and $b|x$ implies $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)|x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The answer at [Show that $x \equiv 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985366/show-that-x-equiv-0) says that $a|x$ and $b|x$ implies $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)|x$. I can see that if $a=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ and $b=\prod p_i^{f_i}$ where $p_i$ is the i-th prime, and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\prod p_i^{max(e_i,f_i)}$ then this kind of shows the result because $x$ has to have prime powers at least $\max(e_i,f_i)$. Is there a way to more directly and/or explicitly motivate this conclusion?

Comment: By definition of $\text{lcm}(a, b) = L$, there are $k, r$ such that $ka = L = rb$. Also since $a|x $ and $b| x$, there are $s, t$ such that $as = x = bt$. But by the definition of $L$ as the least number with such a property, it must be the case that $L|x$.

Comment: @akech: lcm= least common multiple which means "the smallest common multiple".  So your "it must be  the case,,," needs a proof and that is what OP asked. For the same reason, the question which is designated as duplicate does not have proper answers for this question.

Comment: You have a point.

Comment: @JCAA Given that my answer in the dupe  is essentially the same as yours here, your claim that none of them are "proper answers" is puzzling. Did you even read the answers?

Comment: @Gone;  Your answer is 28 lines long and contains a lot of irrelevant information. Are you sure this is the same?

Comment: @JCAA The proof is one line longer *by design* - to highlight the Euclidean descent (in simpler subtractive form). The rest adds insight lacking in your answer (where the proof is pulled out of a hat like magic). Since when is a "longer" (more insightful) answer not a "proper" answer?

Comment: @Gone: You claimed that your answer is essentially the same as mine. That is false. Euclidean descent has nothing to do with OP.

Comment: @JCAA It most certainly does (as you'd learn if you bothered to read the remark in my answer - assuming you know some ideal theory).

Comment: @Gone: I know "some ideal theory". I just do not like bragging about it in answers to elementary questions.

Comment: @JCAA  If you seriously (wrongly) believe that it is "bragging" to make conceptual remarks about how proofs  naturally generalize then our viewpoints about pedagogy are so disparate that there is no point in continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall: $lcm(a,b)$ is the smallest number divisible by $a$ and $b$. If  $lcm(a,b)$ does not divide $x$ we can divide with a remainder:
$x=p\cdot lcm(a,b)+r$ where $r<lcm(a,b)$. But then both $a$ and $b$ divide $r$, so $r\ge lcm(a,b)$, a contradiction.